# If $ u_{n+2}\leq \frac{1}{2}(u_n+u_{n+1})$ then $u_n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $u_n\in \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$ be a positive sequence such that $ u_{n+2}\leq \frac{1}{2}(u_n+u_{n+1}).$
>   Show that $u_n$ is convergent.

Usually I don't post question where I don't have anything but here I cannot make any progress. So a hing is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let

$$v_n := \max \{ u_n, u_{n+1}\}.$$

Show that $(v_n)$ is convergent, and deduce that $(u_n)$ has the same limit.

Comment: I am late, sorry for that. I get $u_{n+1}\le v_n$ and $u_{n+2}\le v_n$ then $(v_n)$ is decreasing, bounded below by $0$ so is convergent.  Now for the last part I get $2v_{n+1}-v_n\le u_{n+1}\le v_n$ so $(u_n)$ has the same limit. Thank you for the hint. +1 and accept.